# Firebase Hosting: How to access website without VPN

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting, vuefire

Many times I cannot access my website without using VPN. This usually happens when the website is hosted on Firebase hosting. Most times, the website will be accessible in the first few weeks but later on it will throw the error below(also see screenshot):
[image]

> This site can’t be reached

Meanwhile it will always work when I use VPN.
This happens to all my users in Nigeria.

Please how do I resolve this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem right now.